# Using a multiline string as an environment variable from a composite action

Tags: github-actions

I have the following composite action:

```
name: 'test'
description: 'test'
outputs:
  out:
    description: output
    value: ${{ env.out }}
runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: "Setup - Checkout"
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: test
      id: plan
      shell: bash
      run: |
        out="hello \n world"
        
        echo "out<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "$out" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

I believe this outputs a multiline string, but my problem is trying to use that in the GitHub actions workflow step below:

```
name: hello-world
jobs:
  my-job:
    outputs:
      out: ${{ steps.test.outputs.out }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checkout the code
      - name: "Setup - Checkout"
        uses: actions/checkout@v2


      - name: test
        id: test
        uses: ./.github/actions/test

  my-job2:
    needs: [my-job]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "test"
        shell: bash
        run: echo ${{ needs.my-job.outputs.out }}
```

My problem is that in `my-job2`, `echo ${{ needs.my-job.outputs.out }}` is empty. Am I not passing the output variable correctly from the composite action?

Comment: See [outputs for composite actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs-for-composite-actions). You need to set it as an output parameter and then use that in the `value`.

Comment: BTW, your custom action is also performing another checkout as well as your job. IMO, it's better let the job do that and the action may raise an error if it's not a git repo if it really needs it instead of doing a checkout.

Answer (score -1):

> Am I not passing the output variable correctly from the composite action?

No, you are not.

You need to [set it as an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs-for-composite-actions):

```yaml
name: 'test'
description: 'test'

outputs:
  out:
    description: output
    value: '${{ steps.plan.outputs.out }}'

runs:
  using: 'composite'

  steps:
    - name: test
      id: plan
      shell: bash
      run: |
        out="hello \n world"
        echo "out=$out" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```